# How to find comments addressed to a person ("@")?

Tags: trello, search

In www.trello.com one may address a card comment to a user using `@name`.

How may I search for comments addressed that way (i.e. comments addressed to me for example)?

If one searches for `@name` one gets the cards assigned to a member, not the comments addressed to a member.

If one searches for `name` one gets all the cards which contain this text somewhere, but not only the cards with comments addressed especially to that name.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such search feature, sorry.

Comments that mention you will show up in your notifications list, though. That might help whittle down your search.